# QGIS, Calculate networks first, diameters second

Tags: qgis, vector, point, network

I need to get the following task done:
First, various points (stored in a shapefile, identified by a common attribute) need to be put into relation with each other (see graphical scheme, steps 1 and 2). Ideally, this would result in a circle encompassing all points. This is where I am a bit lost at the moment because Thiessen/Voronoi/Delaunay polygons aren't of much help here.
Second, and this seems rather easy, the diameter of the resulting polygon should be written out in a text file (see steps 3 and 4). The main goal, as you may imagine by now, is to come up with some idea on what the average *diameter* of a network is. Therefore, if there is any better way to answer this, please don't hesitate to recommend it to me.

I am not familiar with too much Python. However, since this kind of analysis would need to be done a couple of hundred times, I am more than willing to spend some time on learning some scripting/automation.

[image: Scheme]

Comment: Why not convex hull polygon  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could to use coordinate X and Y from the group of point to obtain x min, x max, y min and y max and then you could obtain X and Y from the center and the radius or diameter.

Obviously, you'll obtain 2 data, X and Y, you should to choose the more interesting from your work, mínimun, mean, maximum...

In this way to obtain the circle and the diameter.